# It is possible to select some blocks in grid with CUDA?

Tags: cuda

I have question about control thread blocks in grids.

My source is a recursive job on a image. But in processing, many blocks satisfied end condition about 8 times. Only a few blocks caused execution to loop again more than 16 times. So I want skip the blocks which have satisfied the execution end condition.

It is possible?

```
__global__ main(){
/* previous */
int *blockMap;
cudaMalloc((void**)&blockMap, sizeof(int) * nXBlockNum * nYBlockNum);
cudaMemset((void**)&blockMap, 0, sizeof(int) * nXBlockNum * nYBlockNum);

kernel<<<nblocks, nthreads>>>(inputimage, outputbuffer, blockmap);
/* after */}

__global__
kernel(byte* inputeimage, byte* outputbuffer, int* blockmap) {
    __shared__ int *skipFlag;


    if((blockDim.x * threadIdx.y + threadIdx.x) == 0)
    {
        *skipFlag = g_bMap[blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + blockIdx.x];
    }

    if(*skipFlag == 0)
    {
              /* recursive job */
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean? if you have an `if` condition you can continue running only the active blocks. You can do that even with the threads inside a block.

Comment: simple way is to declare flag for all threads size. but i want to use flag variable having block size. so i declared flag variable in global memory, than using block index so that it does not run. but, in run time it seems to be deadlock condition.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this, but the kernel code you showed is not exactly the way to do it. Presuming that you want an integer flag *for each block*, then the code should look something like:

```
__global__
kernel(byte* inputeimage, byte* outputbuffer, int* blockmap) {
    __shared__ int skipFlag;


    if (threadIdx.x == 0)
    {
        skipFlag = g_bMap[blockIdx.x];
    }
    __syncthreads();

    if(skipFlag == 0)
    {
              /* recursive job */
    }
}
```

Here the first thread in each block loads that particular block's flag from global and stores it to a shared memory integer variable. After block wise synchronisation, each thread can read that value and act on it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand very much your question, but that way seems correct. Each block have an unique `skipFlag` in their shared memory, and those that get `true` don't execute the rest of the code.

And, maybe a `__syncthreads()` between both ifs would be a good idea.